# Custom class defined Perspective in Eclipse RCP Development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have eclipse plugin development, where I am developing everything from scratch. Means I am developing my own workbench with some plugins. so, in my product I am using 7 plugins.

1 is for jar imports, 1 is for soa management and one is for System management.

in this I have define my own class of Perspective.

EAPerspective.java

```
----------
public class EAPerspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {

/**
 * Creates the initial layout for a page.
 */
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();
    addFastViews(layout);
    addViewShortcuts(layout);
    addPerspectiveShortcuts(layout);
    layout.addView("org.governance.ea.platform.parts.soa.WSDLAnalyzerPartView", IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.33f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
    layout.addView("org.governance.ea.platform.parts.soa.EANavigatorPartView", IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.5f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
    layout.addView("org.governance.ea.platform.parts.soa.SOAEditorPartView", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.5f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
}

/**
 * Add fast views to the perspective.
 */
private void addFastViews(IPageLayout layout) {
}

/**
 * Add view shortcuts to the perspective.
 */
private void addViewShortcuts(IPageLayout layout) {
}

/**
 * Add perspective shortcuts to the perspective.
 */
private void addPerspectiveShortcuts(IPageLayout layout) {
}}

----------------------
```

Then I have file "Application.e4xmi"

[image]

My question is platform is loading perspective defined in application.e4xmi but not from the EAPerspective.

I tried everything, earlier I didn't defined anything in application.e4xmi, but later when I defined , I found that it only picks up from the application.e4xmi.

Comment: The Application.e4xmi is for an e4 application. The perspective factory is for a 3.x compatibility mode application. You can't use them both at once.

Comment: then is it possible to have something reltive to PErspective factory in e4? I am also searching now this.

Comment: No, for e4 you define everything in the Application.e4xmi (or a fragment.e4xmi). You need to be clear about the difference between e4 and a 3.x compatibility mode app.